# Only Allow Front End Access

Tags: htaccess, user-access

I am new to wordpress and am looking at a way to **only** allow users access to the front-end of my site.  It is a one page vlog site, but I am forcing users to register to view.

Is this handled in wp-admin, htaccess?  How would i handle this case?

**EDIT**
I am uploading a few videos to my site, and am creating a username and password for two different users that I will be providing them, that they must provide in order to access the site. Registration is not allowed, so basically only those 2 users and myself (the admin) will be able to access the site

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/90535/how-to-redirect-non-admins-to-homepage-if-trying-to-view-mysite-com-wp-admin) will help.

Answer (score 0):

**You want users to Sign Up before they can see any page on your website?**

If that's what you need then I think this is something I can do using jQuery.

Try adding this code to your **footer.php** in the very end before the   tags.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
if (!$("body").hasClass("logged-in")) {
window.location.replace("/register");
}
});
</script>
```

**Now, what this code does?**
Basically every page in WordPress gets the class "logged-in" in the body tag when the user is logged in. So we check if the user is logged in and if they're not then simply redirect them to the register page.

**Still need help? [Contact me.](http://fiverr.com/wpcoderpro)**

Comment: I am uploading a few videos to my site, and am creating a username and password for two different users that I will be providing them, that they must provide in order to access the site.  Registration is not allowed, so basically only those 2 users and myself (the admin) will be able to access the site

Comment: I am not on fiverr -- but am on freelancer, are you?

Comment: @user2676140 No not actually on Freelancer though. You can sing in to Fiverr using Facebook. Or you can talk me on Twitter. twitter.com/wpcoderpro And yes what you're saying that can be attained. I can explain you more if you message me there as it will be too long and public here? :)